# how to synchronize the audio and text files in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates

I have displayed text on below of video as subtitles,now i want to synchronize  that text and video.
How to highlight the text as video plays?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a read of the [ask] section of the [help]. Your question is not a good fit for this site, as we expect your question to contain code (in a [mcve]).  Although to be honest, I feel this question is probably just too broad even if you did provide code

Answer (score 2):

Key the text you want to display by timestamp, and respond to the [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) event from the video media element. Respond to it by querying the [`currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) of the video and updating accordingly.